# Erlang exception error for no match of right hand side value

Tags: erlang, erl

I have this code that is supposed to print the numbers 1 to N-1 in a list, but `I` in here won't append to the list.

```
enum(N,[],N) -> [];
enum(N,L,I) ->
  io:format("current number: ~w~n", [I]),
  L = L ++ I,
enum(N,[],I+1).

enumFunc(N) -> enum(N,[],1).
```

When I run sample:enumFunc(100)., it returns `exception error: no match of right hand side value [1]`

Please help me solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erlang is a single assignment language. This means that you cannot assign a new value to `L` if a value has already been assigned to `L`. When you try to 'assign' a new value via `L = L ++ I` you are actually preforming a *matching* operation. The reason you are seeing the `no match of right hand side value [1]` error is because `L` does not equal `L ++ I` because `L` is already assigned the value of `[1]` and does not match `[1,2]`

```
enum(N,L,N) -> L;
enum(N,L,I) ->
  io:format("current number: ~w~n", [I]),
  L0 = L ++ [I],
  enum(N,L0,I+1).

enumFunc(N) -> enum(N,[],1).
```

Comment: It returned a `Warning: the result of the expression is ignored`.

Comment: Try changing `_L1 = L ++ I` to `_ = L ++ I`.

Comment: There are no more errors, but it still doesn't append anything to the list.

Comment: I've edited my post to show how you can append to the list.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!